# Parallelizable vs. Parallelable

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

Which sentence is correct and meaningful?

> 1. The following computer algorithm is highly parallelizable.
> 2. The following computer algorithm is highly parallelable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parallelizable%2Cparallelable&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparallelizable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparallelable%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cparallelizable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparallelable%3B%2Cc0) It seems like **parallelizable** is far more common, so I believe parallelizable should be preferred over parallelable.

Answer (score 1):

An article in Wikipedia uses various derivatives of "parallelize":

parallelizable
parallelizability
parallelization
**parallelizable**

so it looks like that's the customary term.

[Wikipedia "Parallel algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm#Parallelizability)

I have seen "parallelable" used in reference to electronic inverters, meaning they can be connected in parallel for higher power output, so it's a valid word, but maybe in other contexts.